# run old europa eclipse executable

Tags: eclipse, executable

Downloaded eclipse Europa on laptop as it has 2GB RAM and latest eclipse makes it run slow.

From http://archive.eclipse.org/technology/epp/downloads/release/europa/winter/eclipse-java-europa-winter-win32.zip

Unzipped, clicked eclipse.exe See this error:

[image: java 1.5 required error]

I have Java 7 installed

Can I get java 5? un install Java 7 first? Any easy way to keep both and run old eclipse too?

I know I have java 7 as this works http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp ....

> Verifying Java Version
> A newer version of Java is available
>
> Please click the download button to get the recommended Java for your
> computer. Your Java version: Version 7 Update 40

sys vars

> java_home=C:\apps\j\j\j1645
>
> Path=C:\apps\j\j\j1645\bin;C:\data\apps\j\maven\bin;C:\Program...

**Update**

ty guy - copy jre means copy folder called jre that has bin and lib to folder that has eclipse.exe . worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the jre folder of your java 5 installation into the europa eclipse folder. It will be 'endorsed' and used by the eclipse launcher. Than, feel free to install any other java version on your system. It will not interfere with your eclipse installation.

Comment: Yes. Only the version of the copied jre will be used. I have been using this mode to make sure a specified java version is used when I deploy RCP applications on desktops. And eclipse is just an RCP application.

Comment: copy jre means copy folder called jre that has bin and lib to folder that has eclipse.exe >?